# Adding two scripts inside one javascript file

Tags: sharepoint, content-editor

I have a Content Editor in SharePoint online page I want to add two scripts within a single  Javascript "content.js" and assign "content.js" to the content editor, those two scripts are different, one is a Javascript code to develop something and the other script is Jquery script to design and maintain Select tag that I have.
How to do that with single script

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this within your "content.js" file that you load up via Content Editor:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../Resources/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../Resources/YourCustom.js"><\/script>');
```

Note the use of the escaping slash in the closing </script> tag; this is the simplest approach to loading other JS files via document.write in JS (as opposed to other techniques that say split the tag into two strings).

An alternative would also be to load an HTM file via your Content Editor & have said HTM file load the JS files you wish.

Comment: Dear @Stevangelista thank you so much for your solution, I tried to add the code in the script but it did not work, please could you give me an example about that. sorry I am not that geek in Jscript and content editor. Many Thanks.

Comment: Please post the contents of your "content.js" file and we can check it; I use this approach on a daily basis within SharePoint so I know it works. The way it's loading multiple JS files is not unique to SharePoint either; have you validated you set the correct paths within the "src" attributes?